Simple server side request tracking with lambda@edge
My goal is for a lambda@edge function running on a Cloudfront viewer request event to record to DynamoDB every page request, this will be used later on for tracking activity and producing reports for the website traffic. Basically to avoid using things like Google Analytics, just a simple log of all page requests which won't be able to be blocked by browser extensions etc.
What I'm not sure of is the best way to only record "page" requests, i.e. my first attempt was logging requests for static files such as js, css etc as well as the pages. At the moment I'm excluding various requests from the log call based on the file extension but is there a better way?

If you're interested in relatively basic information, configuring CloudFront access logs and later analyzing them with Athena should be less complex and significantly less expensive as well.
Docs:

CloudFront: Configure and use standard logs (access logs)
Athena: Querying Amazon CloudFront logs


I was going for the lambda approach as it is handling auth too so I can log info like userid along with the requested page url

CloudFront access logs would be the best approach performance and cost wise. If you need to access headers, you can try real-time logs and use cs-headers field.
To target only the first page load, you should be able to do it by checking the referer header value. If it’s different than your host value, it means the request is coming from another site. Assets have the host in referer value as it’s the host itself that loads the assets.
